# What's the purpose of the `VirtualService` in this example?

Tags: istio

I am looking at [this example](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/) of Istio, and they are craeting a `ServiceEntry` and a `VirtualService` to access the external service, but I don't understand why are they creating a `VirtualService` as well.

So, this is the `ServiceEntry`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: edition-cnn-com
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https-port
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```

With just this object, if I try to curl `edition.cnn.com`, I get 200:

```
/ # curl edition.cnn.com -IL 2>/dev/null | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

While I can't access other services:

```
/ # curl google.com -IL
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
location: http://google.com/
date: Fri, 10 Jan 2020 10:12:45 GMT
server: envoy
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

But in the example they create this `VirtualService` as well.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: edition-cnn-com
spec:
  hosts:
  - edition.cnn.com
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - edition.cnn.com
    route:
    - destination:
        host: edition.cnn.com
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
```

What's the purpose of the `VirtualService` in this scenario?.

Answer (score 1):

The `VirtualService` object is basically an abstract pilot resource that modifies envoy filter.
So creating `VirtualService` is a way of modification of envoy and its main purpose is like answering the question: "for a name, how do I route to backends?"

`VirtualService` can also be bound to `Gateway`.

In Your case lack of `VirtualService` results in lack of modification of the envoy from the default/global configuration. That means that the default configuration was enough for this case to work correctly. 
So the `Gateway` which was used was most likely default. With same protocol and port that you requested with curl which all matched Your `ServiceEntry` requirements for connectivity.

This is also mentioned in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services):

> [Virtual
>   services](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService),
>   along with [destination
>   rules](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#destination-rules),
>   are the key building blocks of Istio’s traffic routing functionality.
>   A virtual service lets you configure how requests are routed to a
>   service within an Istio service mesh, building on the basic
>   connectivity and discovery provided by Istio and your platform. Each
>   virtual service consists of a set of routing rules that are evaluated
>   in order, letting Istio match each given request to the virtual
>   service to a specific real destination within the mesh. Your mesh can
>   require multiple virtual services or none depending on your use case.

---

You can use `VirtualService` to add thing like timeout to the connection like in [this](https://istiobyexample.dev/external-services/) example.

---

You can check the routes for Your service with the following command from istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#deep-dive-into-envoy-configuration) `istioctl proxy-config routes <pod-name[.namespace]>`

For bookinfo productpage demo app it is:

```
istioctl pc routes $(kubectl get pod -l app=productpage -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') --name 9080 -o json
```

This way You can check how routes look without `VirtualService` object.

Hope this helps You in understanding istio.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is very specific about this scenario. Any idea what is that VS doing? The command is useful, but it literally spit 3462 lines for a simple 2 container pod.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer: "In Your case lack of `VirtualService` results in lack of modification of the envoy from the default/global configuration." So it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualService is not really doing anything, but as the [docs say](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/):

> creating a VirtualService with a default route for every service, right from the start, is generally considered a best practice in Istio

---

The **ServiceEntry** adds the CNN site as an entry to Istio’s internal service registry, so auto-discovered services in the mesh can route to these manually specified services.

Usually that's used to allow monitoring and other Istio features of external services from the start, whereas the **VirtualService** would allow the proper routing of request (basically traffic management).

[This page](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#controlled-access-to-external-services) in the docs gives a bit more background info on using ServiceEntries and VirtualServices, but basically the ServiceEntry makes sure your mesh knows about the service and can monitor it, and the VirtualService controls what traffic is going to the service, which in this case is all of it.

Comment: thank you! I think it would make sense to use a VS in this scenario, if I would be using egress gateway; to send the traffic to the gateway itself.